# D3: set bar colors according to property selected from drop down menu

Tags: d3.js

I have a very basic question. I have a species/abundance csv that is plotted as a bar chart. The data set includes headers of properties like genus, location, etc. I want to color the bars with `d3.scaleOrdinal()` depending on the header/property selected from a drop down menu with the properties name. I do not know the header/properties before loading the csv.

So, if the user selects "location" the bars will be colored according to the location, etc. If the user makes no selection the colorbars should all have the same color.

How can I select the property from my data to create my scale domain? Is this the best way

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) {
  d.abundance = +d.abundance;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  //color domain
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory10);

  //dropdown menu from csv header
  var select = d3.select('body')
    .append('select')
    .attr('class','select')
    .on('change',onchange)
    .selectAll('option')
      .data(d3.keys(data[0])).enter()
      .append('option')
      .text(function (d) { return d; });

  function onchange() {
    selectValue = d3.select('select').property('value')
    color.domain( data.map(function(d) { return d.selectValue; }) )
    g.selectAll(".bar")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.selectValue); })
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any property named `selectValue` in your data array. `selectValue` is just an variable that holds the name of the actual property.

Therefore, you should use *bracket notation* instead of dot notation:

```
color.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d[selectValue];
}))
g.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d[selectValue]);
    })
```

Besides that, two additional tips:

1. You don't need this...

   ```
   selectValue = d3.select('select').property('value')
   ```

   ... to get the selected value. Just do:

   ```
   var selectValue = this.value;
   ```
2. You don't need this...

   ```
   d3.keys(data[0]))
   ```

   ... to get the column headers. You can just do:

   ```
   data.columns
   ```